# Unfocusing an input field in a web view

Tags: javascript, jquery, javafx-2

My JavaFX application is displaying a web page, using a web view.

I need to intercept whenever the user focuses a text input field (`<input>`), in order to allow him to type the value either with the keyboard (normal behavior), or using an Android application.

For this second part, I have binded a jQuery callback, using `WebEngine.executeScript()`method and this Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).on('focus', 'input[type=text]', myCallback);
```

`myCallback` is a function which raises an event inside my Java application. When the user has finished editing (i.e. by pressing <kbd>OK</kbd> on Android app, by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on keyboard...), **I need to *unfocus* the input field**. So, what I have tried:

- Unfocusing in Javascript, using `$(":input").blur();`
- Focusing an other element, in Javascript, using `$("a").focus()`
- Unfocusing the web view, using `webView.getParent().requestFocus()`.

The last one is my *best* try: the input field is unfocused. Unfortunately, it is focused again as soon as the user clicks on the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I need to make Javascript calls (using `executeScript()`) in Java FX thread (`Platform.invokeLater()`).

In fact, all solutions provided in the question are working.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps...

```
$('input').each(function(){
  $(this).trigger('blur');
  //each input event one by one... will be blured
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as other solutions found so far, it does not work in a JavaFX WebView. Thanks anyway!